# How to represent multiple data by single value

Tags: clustering, mean, aggregation, centering

I have three inputs x1,x2,x3 and to each single input there are three outputs y1, y2, y3.

(1) x1 --y1, y2, y3
(2) x2 --y1, y2, y3
(3) x3 --y1, y2, y3
The Whole whole set has to be represented by single y value.
What aggregation formulae can be applied?
(Formula from any science field can be applied.)
The effect of input x should be considered in calculating y.

Comment: What is the purpose of such a representation?  That information ought to help determine the solution.

Comment: the purpose is to compare different datasets

Comment: That's quite obscure: could you explain what is the nature of the comparison and how encoding this information could support the intended comparison?

Comment: There are many datasets, general expression is shown above. In order to have rational  comparison for further processing,  a single representative value is required. Hope this clarifies...

Answer (score 0):

X   Y

x1  y1

x1  y2

x1  y3

x2  y1

x2  y2

x2  y3

x3  y1

x3  y2

x3  y3

I would format your data like this, from here you could take a simple average of all 9 Y values, or take a weighted average of Y values by X. Why does the whole set have to be represented by a single Y value?